# ng2 charts bar chart need spacing between 2 bars in series Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am working on Angular app with ng2-charts. I am trying to show two series data in one bar chart graph. I am able to do it successfully but my bars are sticking two each other. I want space between my  two bars.

[image]

If I remove the bar thickness from data it automatically takes the space bbetween bars but then bar are so thick which are not as per my design.
I am trying to acheive something like https://appstack.bootlab.io/charts-chartjs.html this website.

Below is my code.

**chart.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart 
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [colors] = "barChartColors"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**Chart.ts**

```
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
     scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    responsive: true,
    cornerRadius: 100,
    plugins: {
      labels: {
        render: 'value'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'black',
        boxWidth: 20,
        padding: 20,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        fontSize: 13
      }
    },
    animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];
  public barChartColors = [{
   backgroundColor: '#3f80ea',
      borderColor: '#3f80ea',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)',
      borderWidth: 3
  }]
    public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A', barThickness  :10 },
      { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B', barThickness  :10}
    ];
```

Any help will be highly appreciated as I am trying my level best as beginner to get through this

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you mean, you want each part of the bar chart to be doubled
That means show you two pieces of data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvT49.png)

Now you just need to write the scales section like this

```
 scales: {
  x: {
    stacked: true,
  },
  y: {
    stacked: true,
  }
},
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartData, ChartEvent, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

import DataLabelsPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective | undefined;

  public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    // scales: {
    //   x: {},
    //   y: {
    //     min: 10
    //   }
    // },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end'
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartPlugins = [
    DataLabelsPlugin
  ];

  public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
    datasets: [
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
      { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
    ]
  };

  // events
  public chartClicked({ event, active }: { event?: ChartEvent, active?: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public chartHovered({ event, active }: { event?: ChartEvent, active?: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public randomize(): void {
    // Only Change 3 values
    this.barChartData.datasets[0].data = [
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      59,
      80,
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      56,
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      40];

    this.chart?.update();
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div style="display: block">
            <canvas baseChart [data]="barChartData" [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins" [type]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
      </canvas>
        </div>
        <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="randomize()">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**It really is not very likely, but I am using the latest Angular version**

Comment: No I want space between two bars in same series. If you see the blue and lightblue bar both are stick togather and there is no space between them see the link below
https://appstack.bootlab.io/charts-chartjs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a space between - you can add another dataset, something like this:

```
public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
    datasets: [
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
      { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], label: '' },
      { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
    ]
  };
```